# Rotating Around a Point

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I have a ship texture, and just below the ship's port wing is a missile texture. When I rotate the ship, I need the missile to stay in the same position relative to the ship (i.e., under the port wing). I read some articles and came up with this (sorry, it's a bit messy):

```
        private void RotateWeapons()
    {
        float x, y;
        /*
        x = leftMissile.X + (radius * (float)Math.Cos(Rotation));
        y = leftMissile.Y + (radius * (float)Math.Sin(Rotation));
        */

        leftMissile = Vector2.Transform(leftMissile - center, Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Backward, Rotation)) + center;

        //leftMissile.X = x;
        //leftMissile.Y = y;
    }
```

Where `leftMissile` is a `Vector2` describing the middle of the missile, and `center` is the center of the ship as a `Vector2`. It almost works, the sprite rotates around the center. The problem is, it doesn't stay at the same point on the port wing.

This is normal:
[image: This is normal]

This is 90 degrees, it's further off the wing:
[image: 90 Degree Rotation]

And when rotated 180 degrees, it's not even on the ship anymore:
[image: 180 Degree Rotation]

Comment: I'd try removing `center` from the calculation of the rotation and see how that affected the result.

Comment: I tried removing center from the beginning and end, independantly. It did the same thing...

Comment: Hmm - how are the textures defined and where is (0,0) on each?

Comment: Origin points are the centres of each sprite individually. And textures are standard Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2Ds, loaded by the Game.Content.Load<T>() function.

Comment: Jack - that's why the problem occurs and why Scott W's solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should consider doing is keeping a constant (`readonly`) *offset* from your ship for the missile:

```
//non-rotated, where is the missile relative to the ship?
readonly Vector2 missileOffset = new Vector2(5.0f, 2.0f);
```

This keeps things in the ship's relative space. Then you can simply transform only the offset, and then add this to the ship's position:

```
//rotation of ship as quaternion
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Backward, angle);
//the final position for the missile
Vector2 leftMissile = Vector2.Transform(missileOffset, rotation) + shipPosition;
```

This will get the missile in the proper place. Then, assuming you're using `SpriteBatch`, just rotate both ship and missile by passing in the angle to both:

```
batch.Begin();
batch.Draw(shipTex, shipPosition, null, Color.White, angle, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
batch.Draw(missileTex, leftMissile, null, Color.White, angle, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0f);
batch.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a forward vector and the center, is easy to calc it.

[image]

1. Normalize forward.

   Forward.Normalize();
2. Get a normal vector to forward.

   Normal.X = Forward.Y; Normal.Y = -Forward.X;
3. Get the pos of the missile.

   MissilePos = CenterShip - Forward * OffsetY (+ or -) Normal * OffsetX;